# DH Private exponent length for key exchange

Tags: openssl

we are using MODP Group 14 RFC-3526 in our SSL Handshake Setup, there is a security requirement "Private DH exponent length for key exchange must be minimum 256 bit"

how we know which Private DH Exponent length is in use, is it DH Private Key size?

OpenSSL generates actual private key internaly.

From tmp_dh_callback, we are returning the following dh:

```
DH* dh = DH_new();
DH_set0_pqg(dh, BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048, NULL, DH_GENERATOR_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case the length of DH exponent length is 2048.

Initializing the DH parameters with [`BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/BN_get_rfc3526_prime_2048.html) you explicitly selected [2048-bit MODP group](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3526#section-3).